# Error OS2 no such file or directory

Tags: r, sublimetext2, sublimerepl

I am trying to launch R from sublimetext2 via sublimeREPL. Until I installed the new OS everything worked, now not anymore since the directory is not found apparently. I tried all variations but I cannot make it work. Here are my SublimeREPL User settings:

```
{
"default_extend_env": {"PATH": "{PATH}:/Applications/R"},
"default_extend_env":{"COLUMNS": "500"},
"wrap_width": 200,
"word_wrap": false,
 "pep8_ignore":["E251","E501","W191","E303"]
}
```

Any idea what this might be about?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it: After installing "el capitan", the permissions to access for sublime seemed to be deleted. I reeinstalled R and all worked.